# Contagem de registros

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Tenho uma tabela chamada `cad_faltas`, ele possui os campos:

```
id int(11)
id_cad_alunos int(11) 
falta varchar(8)
idcurso int(11)
```

O campo `falta` recebe os dados AUSENTE e/ou PRESENTE. A questão é, existe alguma possibilidade de fazer uma contagem de registos que estão como "AUSENTE" para cada `idcurso` e também saber a percentagem de registos com esta informação?

Exemplo:

> Para o curso de "id" 2 existem três registros como "AUSENTE" que são
>   50% de todos registros para esta "id" 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o que você precisa é a quantidade de faltas e percentual por curso, segue uma maneira de fazer:

```
SELECT
  a.idcurso,
  nmfaltas,
  (nmfaltas * 100) / COUNT(*) percfaltas
FROM
  cad_faltas a
JOIN
  (SELECT idcurso, COUNT(*) nmfaltas FROM cad_faltas where falta = 'AUSENTE' GROUP BY idcurso) b on a.idcurso = b.idcurso
GROUP BY idcurso
```

> [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b73f/8)

Answer (score 1):

Como você precisa tanto a quantidade de registros com ausentes como presentes, uma cláusula `where` se torna inviável. O que é possível fazer é calcular a soma de valores, para definir o número de ausentes, definindo o valor 1 quando o registro é ausente ou 0 quando é presente. A soma será a quantidade de registros ausentes. Já para calcular a parcela que esse valor representa do total, você pode calcular o valor médio, também definindo o valor 1 quando é ausente ou 0 quando é presente. Veja um exemplo:

```
select 
  sum(case when falta = "AUSENTE" then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as ausentes, 
  100*avg(case when falta = "AUSENTE" then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as parcela,
  idcurso
from cad_faltas 
group by idcurso;
```

> Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b99b97/1/0).